# code 1284 Class "Sample" is reserved for use by Microsoft; code 1293 Service "ECHO" is reserved

Tags: echo, wdk, kmdf, windows-driver

I am trying to run the echo demo from [this repository](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/general/echo/kmdf), but got some errors as the image shows below, anyone knows how to solve this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D50pJ.png)

I had tried from this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/from-sample-code-to-production-driver

finally I solved the ploblems, but I donnot know why.